# Connecting a Long Stem Thermometer to an Arduino to automate the recording of temperature in an experiment

Tags: arduino-uno, hardware

Is there a way to connect and read the output of a long stem thermometer like this one to an Arduino?

[image]

Comment: That won't be easy. You'll have to break one open, and see what's inside. Maybe a thermistor, which you could connect to an arduino analog pin, but you'd have to manually calibrate it.

Comment: I actually found one here: https://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2013/07/25/an-arduino-powered-bbq-thermometer/ do you think I can do these? I am not really in to electronics just need this for my biorector for thesis.

Comment: If that unit also contains a thermistor, you can indeed follow that guide. But you'd have to open it first to find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interfacing with a temperature sensor such as the DS18B20 (https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11050) would be much simpler than trying to interface with a thermometer with unknown internals.

Theoretically, yes, you can use the thermometer you posted, but it won't be simple. The only way to know what you would have to do to interface with it is to open it up and see what's inside. You would still have to calibrate it though to make any sense of the readings you get from it.